# Unity3D UI acting differently in editor than device

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

Within my code I have the following lines within my `LateUpdate` function:

```
if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
{
      if (Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch(1).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
      {

      float dot = Vector2.Dot(Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.normalized, Input.GetTouch(1).deltaPosition.normalized);

      if (dot < fingerSepValue )
      {
          CameraZoom();
      }
      else
      {
          MoveCamera();
      }
    }

    if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        var touchDeltaPosition = CameraOrbit();
    }
}
```

This code should only run if the user isn't touching the UI layer. This works within my Unity project just fine, but when I build to iPad, no matter where I touch on the screen (be it the UI or otherwise) the camera movement code gets called.

Does anyone know the reason for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same thing using events like IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler. Then you have to add Physics Raycaster to camera and collider to game object containing script. Or you can look for a solution here if you have to use IsPointerOverGameObject http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/touch-press-pass-through-all-ui-elements.272892/